# Zod validation schema make field required based on another array field

Tags: reactjs, validation, zod

I have a Zod validation schema with an array field and a string field:

```
const zodSchema = z.object({
  goals: z.array(z.string()).nonempty("At least one goal is required"),
  goals_other: z.string(),
});
```

How do I make the `goals_other` field required ONLY if `goals` array includes the string "Other"?

I tried a refine function like the following but it didn't work

```
const zodSchema = z
  .object({
    goals: z.array(z.string()).nonempty("At least one goal is required"),
    goals_other: z.string(),
  })
  .refine((data) => (data.goals.includes("Other") ? true : false), {
    message: "Required, please specify other goals",
    path: ["goals_other"],
  });
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a straightforward way to get the behavior you want assuming that you are ok with the schema failing to parse if bad data is present in the `goals_other` field when `'Other'` is not included in the list. I will show this approach first:

```js
import { z } from "zod";

const zodSchema = z
  .object({
    goals: z.array(z.string()).nonempty("At least one goal is required"),
    goals_other: z.string().optional() // optional to avoid failing when it's missing
  })
  .superRefine(({ goals, goals_other }, ctx) => {
    // Here we add the extra check to assert the field exists when
    // the "Other" goal is present.
    if (goals.includes("Other") && goals_other === undefined) {
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: "custom",
        message: "Required, please specify other goals",
        path: ["goals_other"]
      });
    }
  });

console.log(zodSchema.safeParse({
  goals: ['test'],
})); // success
console.log(zodSchema.safeParse({
  goals: ['Other'],
})); // failure
console.log(zodSchema.safeParse({
  goals: ['Other'],
  goals_other: 11,
})); // failure (because goals_other is not a string)
console.log(zodSchema.safeParse({
  goals: ['Other'],
  goals_other: 'test',
})); // success
```

But there is a problem IMO with this:

```js
zodSchema.safeParse({
  goals: ['test'],
  goals_other: 11,
}); // Failure
```

This attempt to parse is a failure, because the `goals_other` field is expected to be a `string | undefined` and it got a number. If you truly do not care about the `goals_other` field unless there is the `"Other"` goal in your goals list, then what you really want is to ignore the field until you find the other string and then to validate.

```js
const zodSchema = z
  .object({
    goals: z.array(z.string()).nonempty("At least one goal is required"),
    goals_other: z.unknown(),
  })
  .superRefine(({ goals, goals_other }, ctx) => {
    if (goals.includes("Other")) {
      if (goals_other === undefined) {
        ctx.addIssue({
          code: "custom",
          message: "Required, please specify other goals",
          path: ["goals_other"]
        });
      } else if (typeof goals_other !== 'string') {
        ctx.addIssue({
          code: 'custom',
          message: 'expected a string',
          path: ['goals_other'],
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

This schema would parse correctly, but it doesn't refine the output type. `other_goals` will have type `unknown` which is somewhat unhelpful. You could fix this with a type assertion in a `transform` but that feels a little bit awkward too. It might be best to just go ahead with the first schema and accept that you're not actually ignoring the `goals_other` field when `"Other"` is not present. So long as other data doesn't end up in there in the values you're parsing, you're not going to have a problem.