Why does my .Refine is not working properly when I tried to make a conditional input field?
I created a conditional input field wherein if the user selected yes, it will prompt another 3 input fields. How can I make the input field required and show a warning if the if the user selected yes?
const FormSchema = z.object({
  type: z.enum(["yes", "no"], {
    required_error: "You need to select a notification type.",
  }),
  dryRunDate: z.string().optional(),
  dryRunStart: z.string().optional(),
  dryRunEnd: z.string().optional(),
}).refine(data => {
  if (data.type === 'yes') {
    return data.dryRunDate && data.dryRunStart && data.dryRunEnd;
  }
  return true;
});


export default function RadioGroupForm() {
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      type: "no",
      dryRunDate: "",
      dryRunStart: "",
      dryRunEnd: ""
    }
  });

const hasDryRun = form.watch("type");
This is my form.tsx
<Form {...form}>

  <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="w-2/3 space-y-6">
    <FormField
      control={form.control}
      name="type"
      render={({ field }) => (
        <FormItem className="space-y-3">
          <FormLabel>Optional;</FormLabel>
          <FormControl>
            <RadioGroup
              onValueChange={field.onChange}
              defaultValue={field.value}
              className="flex flex-col space-y-1"
            >
              <FormItem className="flex items-center space-x-3 space-y-0">
                <FormControl>
                  <RadioGroupItem value="yes" />
                </FormControl>
                <FormLabel className="font-normal">yes</FormLabel>
              </FormItem>
              <FormItem className="flex items-center space-x-3 space-y-0">
                <FormControl>
                  <RadioGroupItem value="no" />
                </FormControl>
                <FormLabel className="font-normal">no</FormLabel>
              </FormItem>

              {hasDryRun === "yes" && (
                <>
                  <FormField
                    control={form.control}
                    name="dryRunDate"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <FormItem>
                        <FormLabel>dryRunDate</FormLabel>
                        <FormControl>
                          <Input type="date" placeholder="date" {...field} />
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormMessage />
                      </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />
                  <FormField
                    control={form.control}
                    name="dryRunStart"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <FormItem>
                        <FormLabel>Dry Run Start</FormLabel>
                        <FormControl>
                          <Input type="time" placeholder="start" {...field} />
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormMessage />
                      </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />
                  <FormField
                    control={form.control}
                    name="dryRunEnd"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <FormItem>
                        <FormLabel>Dry Run End</FormLabel>
                        <FormControl>
                          <Input type="time" placeholder="end" {...field} />
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormMessage />
                      </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />
                </>
              )}
            </RadioGroup>
          </FormControl>
          <FormMessage />
        </FormItem>
      )}
    />
    <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
  </form>
</Form>


What is the problem?

the problem I encounter is, I have the ability to skip the 3 fields which are dryRunDate, dryRunStart and dryRunEnd if I select yes, which is i'm trying to solve it by making it required.

What about https://stackoverflow.com/a/77121464/18079514 ?

I don't know if this right answer but it works on me. I check on this
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76342806/ and this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77121215. And I've come up with this function
const FormSchema = z.object({
  type: z.enum(["yes", "no"], {
    required_error: "You need to select a notification type.",
  }),
  dryRunDate: z.string().optional(),
  dryRunStart: z.string().optional(),
  dryRunEnd: z.string().optional(),
}).superRefine(({ type, dryRunDate, dryRunStart, dryRunEnd }, ctx) => {
  if (type === 'yes') {
    if (!dryRunDate) {
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: 'custom',
        message: 'dryRunDate is required to fill up if you choose yes.',
        path: ['dryRunDate']
      })
    }
    if (!dryRunStart) {
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: 'custom',
        message: 'dryRunStart is required to fill up if you choose yes.',
        path: ['dryRunStart']
      })
    }
    if (!dryRunEnd) {
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: 'custom',
        message: 'dryRunEnd is required to fill up if you choose yes.',
        path: ['dryRunEnd']
      })
    }
  }
});



